# WebRTC: Consent refresh timed out, Consent refresh failed, setting pair to state CANCELLED

Tags: webrtc

First of all, this is probably not going to be a great question, since I don't have much understanding of WebRTC. The problem is tho that we have been having problems with our videochat app based on WebRTC for months and our developers can't seem to fix it.

So, we use adapter.js to set everything up, but the past 2-3 months there have been loads of problems where user's video images just freeze and they have to leave the conversation and be invited back in. Then another user's screen freezes and the whole circus starts all over again.

In this case there's a conversation leader using Windows 10 and the newest version of Chrome, who connects to 3-4 other locations which all use ChromeOS based PCs. We have it set up so that the conversation leader can see all the locations, but the locations do not see each other, they only see the conversation leader. This is done because the locations are following lessons through the video connection.

I never could find anything weird in the console or log files, up until today when my own screen froze while in the conversation and trying to troubleshoot the problem. I use Firefox by the way

My console said "ICE candidate failed, see about:webrtc for information", and when checking that page I found what I'm showing below. Does anyone have any idea what's going on here?

Here's a link to the full log: https://www.onsplatform.tv/home/files/aboutWebrtc.html

```
...
(ice/INFO) ICE(PC:1489051912852000 (id=619 url=https://www.onsplatform.tv/bewegenopafstand/beeldbellen/room/90bd4022-0524-45fd-bdd1-546b2a2853a5))/STREAM(0-1489051912852000 (id=619 url=https://www.onsplatform.tv/bewegenopafstand/beeldbellen/room/90bd4022-0524-45fd-bdd1-546b2a2853a5) aLevel=0)/COMP(1): Consent refreshed

(stun/INFO) Unrecognized attribute: 0xc057
(stun/INFO) Unrecognized attribute: 0xc057
(stun/INFO) STUN-CLIENT(consent): Received response; processing
(ice/INFO) ICE(PC:1489051912852000 (id=619 url=https://www.onsplatform.tv/bewegenopafstand/beeldbellen/room/90bd4022-0524-45fd-bdd1-546b2a2853a5))/STREAM(0-1489051912852000 (id=619 url=https://www.onsplatform.tv/bewegenopafstand/beeldbellen/room/90bd4022-0524-45fd-bdd1-546b2a2853a5) aLevel=0)/COMP(1): Consent refreshed

(stun/INFO) Unrecognized attribute: 0xc057
(stun/INFO) Unrecognized attribute: 0xc057
(stun/INFO) STUN-CLIENT(consent): Received response; processing
(ice/INFO) ICE(PC:1489051912852000 (id=619 url=https://www.onsplatform.tv/bewegenopafstand/beeldbellen/room/90bd4022-0524-45fd-bdd1-546b2a2853a5))/STREAM(0-1489051912852000 (id=619 url=https://www.onsplatform.tv/bewegenopafstand/beeldbellen/room/90bd4022-0524-45fd-bdd1-546b2a2853a5) aLevel=0)/COMP(1): Consent refreshed

(stun/INFO) Unrecognized attribute: 0xc057
(stun/INFO) Unrecognized attribute: 0xc057
(stun/INFO) STUN-CLIENT(consent): Received response; processing
(ice/INFO) ICE(PC:1489051912852000 (id=619 url=https://www.onsplatform.tv/bewegenopafstand/beeldbellen/room/90bd4022-0524-45fd-bdd1-546b2a2853a5))/STREAM(0-1489051912852000 (id=619 url=https://www.onsplatform.tv/bewegenopafstand/beeldbellen/room/90bd4022-0524-45fd-bdd1-546b2a2853a5) aLevel=0)/COMP(1): Consent refreshed

(stun/INFO) Unrecognized attribute: 0xc057
(ice/WARNING) ICE(PC:1489051912852000 (id=619 url=https://www.onsplatform.tv/bewegenopafstand/beeldbellen/room/90bd4022-0524-45fd-bdd1-546b2a2853a5))/STREAM(0-1489051912852000 (id=619 url=https://www.onsplatform.tv/bewegenopafstand/beeldbellen/room/90bd4022-0524-45fd-bdd1-546b2a2853a5) aLevel=0)/COMP(1): Consent refresh timed out

(ice/INFO) ICE(PC:1489051912852000 (id=619 url=https://www.onsplatform.tv/bewegenopafstand/beeldbellen/room/90bd4022-0524-45fd-bdd1-546b2a2853a5))/STREAM(0-1489051912852000 (id=619 url=https://www.onsplatform.tv/bewegenopafstand/beeldbellen/room/90bd4022-0524-45fd-bdd1-546b2a2853a5) aLevel=0)/COMP(1): Consent refresh failed

(ice/INFO) ICE-PEER(PC:1489051912852000 (id=619 url=https://www.onsplatform.tv/bewegenopafstand/beeldbellen/room/90bd4022-0524-45fd-bdd1-546b2a2853a5):default)/CAND-PAIR(br08): setting pair to state CANCELLED: br08|IP4:192.168.2.176:49339/UDP|IP4:192.168.2.176:52952/UDP(turn-relay(IP4:192.168.178.25:56515/TCP|IP4:192.168.2.176:49339/UDP)|candidate:1502217555 1 udp 25042687 192.168.2.176 52952 typ relay raddr 80.113.157.125 rport 53996 generation 0 ufrag 9oaG network-id 1)

(ice/INFO) ICE-PEER(PC:1489051912852000 (id=619 url=https://www.onsplatform.tv/bewegenopafstand/beeldbellen/room/90bd4022-0524-45fd-bdd1-546b2a2853a5):default): all checks completed success=0 fail=1

(stun/INFO) STUN-CLIENT(consent): Timed out

+++++++ END ++++++++
```

Comment: Did you ever resolve this since or find a workaround? We're seeing this exact behaviour as well but only in Firefox so far. And it's not consistent either even on the same computer. 1 in 10 times on the same computer on the same network in the same page load, connecting for playback to our Wowza Streaming Engine server will seemingly succeed and then: (1) the video and audio freezes, (2) a second or two later we the `iceConnectionState` changes to `"disconnected"`, (3) 10-ish seconds later connection state becomes `"failed"` and we get that same "Consent refresh failed"  error.

Comment: [It appears to be related to this behaviour](https://blog.mozilla.org/webrtc/ice-disconnected-not/)

Comment: @Brandon I never got an answer sadly, we had these problems only with a specific client of ours, they had various locations throughout the city where our videochat application was used. They eventually didn't renew the contract because of the problems, but no other client has had these problems since. Pretty sure it's a problem with a very specific firewall or network configuration on the client's side. Their IT department never really bothered to properly look into it either.

Comment: No problem, thanks for the reply. We weren't able to fix it either and chalked it up to the server-side not properly handling consent checks from Firefox and filed a bug with Wowza who builds the streaming server we're using.

Comment: Hello, do you have anything new about this problem? Struggling with the same one, i think

Comment: I have the same behavior :/, only on firefox using coturn and simple peer